# Kronecker product connected?

Tags: kronecker-product

Hi I've started looking at Kronecker products and was wondering if anyone had an intuitive explanation as to why the Kronecker product of two graphs is connected iff one(or both) contain an odd cycle. I've looked at proofs but am not really getting a proper feel of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe the claim presented is true. Look at the cyclic graph $G_3$ of order 3. Let $A_3$ be the agency matrix of $G_3$, given by
$\begin{pmatrix}
\ & 1 & \ \\
\ & \ & 1 \\
1 & \ & \
\end{pmatrix}$ for some permutation of the indices. Then the Kronecker product $A_3\otimes A_3$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}
\ & A_3 & \ \\
\ & \ & A_3 \\
A_3 & \ & \
\end{pmatrix}$, with corresponding graph: [$A_3\otimes A_3$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fW1.png)

Comment: So my answer is flawed in the following way: I gave the adjacency graph of a **directed** cyclic graph of order 3. If I had been thinking properly and written it as an **undirected** graph, the claim would hold. Many apologies.

Answer (score 4):

This all fails if the graphs aren't connected, so we assume that they both are.

Assume none of the graphs have odd cycles. Then both of them are bipartite. Let $G, H$ be the two graphs, and let $G_1, G_2$ be the bipartite partition of $G$ and $H_1, H_2$ the bipartite partition of $H$. Then let a vertex $(g, h)$ in $G\otimes H$ be called *even* if $g\in G_1, h\in H_1$ or $g\in G_2, h\in H_2$ and uneven otherwise. It is clear that even vertices only have even neighbours, and the same for uneven, so the product is disconnected.

Now assume that $G$ is nonbipartite (i.e. it has an odd cycle), and let $(g, h)$ and $(g', h')$ be two vertices in $G\otimes H$. Say we have a path $gg_1g_2\cdots g_ng'$ from $g$ to $g'$ in $G$ that goes at least one complete lap around an odd cycle in $G$, and a path $hh_1h_2\cdots h_mh'$ from $h$ to $h'$ in $H$.

Since we can add laps around the odd cycle as we like, we may assume that the path in $G$ is at least as long as the path in $H$, i.e. $n \geq m$. If they are equal, then $(g, h)(g_1, h_1)\cdots (g_n, h_n)(g',h')$ is a path in $G\otimes H$, and we're done. If not, there are two cases:

1. $n-m$ is even. In this case, extend the path in $H$ by going back and forth between two neighbours to get a path like $hh_1hh_1\cdots hh_1hh_1h_2\cdots h_mh'$ that has the same length as the path in $G$. Now these two paths together make a path in $G\otimes H$ between $(g, h)$ and $(g',h')$.
2. $n-m$ is odd. In this case, extend the path in $G$ by going one additional lap around the odd cycle. Now the difference in length of the path in $G$ and the path in $H$ is even, and you can apply 1. above.

There isn't really much more intuition to get, I think. The Kronecker product is such an abstract construction that you have to get into the nitty-grutty details to prove anything this basic.

Comment: Thank u very much. I, for some reason, thought that there was some obvious one line intuitive explanation that I just wasn't getting, but the kronecker product is quite abstract and the above proof makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Showing that a graph is connected usually done by taking two arbitrary vertices and constructing a path between them. That's usually quite basic, but may be lengthy.

Comment: Hi Arthur, May I ask was there somewhere in particular you saw this proof, or if you just wrote it from knowledge. curiosity!

Comment: @moony I came up with it more or less on the spot. It's mostly a matter of having the definition of connected graph and of the product in your head, knowing where you want to end up, and getting there in a natural way. For instance, we want to make a path from $(g,h)$ to $(g',h')$. Starting with paths from $g$ to $g'$ and from $h$ to $h'$ seems like a good idea. Then see what you have to do in order to make the two paths you have into the path you want (i.e. make the two paths the same length). To guarantee that it can be done, one of the two paths must be extendable by an odd number of steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your proof and reasoning make much more sense to me than the proofs I've read. Thanks:)